# Change "no time was spent" to 0 in variable

Tags: r

I am very new to R, and also to posting on forums, but I have found other Q&A threads really useful so thought I would give it a try!

I have a variable for "% of senior management time spent dealing with government regulations". This, of course, includes numbers from 0 to 100 but also "no time was spent" and "don't know". This means it is structured as a factor.

For other variables, I have been using unfactor() followed by as.numeric() to coerce the "don't knows" into NAs and retain the underlying values. However, here I want "no time was spent" to be treated as 0, and "don't know" to be treated as NA.

Is there any way of doing this?

#### Edit for reproducible example

```
> head(Benin2016$j2)
[1] No time was spent 5                 50                1                
[5] No time was spent 20               
23 Levels: 1 10 100 12 15 2 20 25 3 30 4 40 48 5 50 6 67 70 72 80 ... No time was spent

> dput(Benin2016$j2)
structure(c(23L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 23L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 14L, 1L, 
22L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 8L, 14L, 6L, 23L, 23L, 6L, 16L, 19L, 1L, 14L, 
15L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 10L, 1L, 9L, 23L, 1L, 9L, 23L, 23L, 6L, 7L, 
19L, 23L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 14L, 1L, 4L, 20L, 14L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 6L, 
2L, 9L, 22L, 23L, 6L, 6L, 14L, 1L, 23L, 6L, 22L, 2L, 6L, 23L, 
14L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 23L, 22L, 14L, 22L, 23L, 2L, 22L, 
14L, 23L, 4L, 14L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 18L, 4L, 1L, 23L, 17L, 23L, 22L, 
6L, 22L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 23L, 22L, 2L, 22L, 6L, 14L, 1L, 22L, 2L, 
14L, 23L, 6L, 22L, 22L, 12L, 11L, 14L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 20L, 3L, 22L, 
21L, 21L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 23L, 21L, 6L, 22L, 6L, 6L, 
8L, 15L, 23L, 9L, 6L, 23L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 23L), .Label = c("1", 
"10", "100", "12", "15", "2", "20", "25", "3", "30", "4", "40", 
"48", "5", "50", "6", "67", "70", "72", "80", "90", "Don't know (spontaneous)", 
"No time was spent"), class = "factor")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing a reproducible example, but this is one way to do it:

```
dataframe$variable[dataframe$variable=="no time was spent"] <- 0
dataframe$variable[dataframe$variable=="don't know"] <- "NA"
```

Where dataframe is the name of your dataframe, and variable is the name of your variable (here % of senior management time spent dealing with government regulations, if I understood correctly).

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me! I tried this but got `Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, Benin2016$j2 == "No time was spent", value = c(NA,  : invalid factor level, NA generated`. The "No time was spent" entries are now NAs. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi again, I used `dataframe <- read.csv("path/to/file.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and then the code you suggested and it now works, thanks!

Comment: @Cassie great! Happy coding!